# How to delete single record in details list with same Id in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, delete-record

I'm working on a project in which i have to deal with Staff accounts and in Accounts details i have more then one enteries with same id and I want to delete single record from the list without effecting others row with same Id

Comment: Describe what have you already done. Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make it unique first. You can, for example, use the id=id_index so in this case when you are deleting it is unique.
Also, if it is just removing from the interface you can use 'this' keyword inside change event by using jquery.